# How can I display the Ionic loading overlay when cached data is returned from HTTP call?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I want to display ionicLoading when I call a WebService, I'm using an interceptor to do this and it's working. I am also using HTTP caching, but when a WebService is called and is called at least once (so cache is called and it's working), the ionicLoading is not displayed.

Here is my code for caching:

```
$httpProvider.defaults.cache = true;
```

And here is my code for the interceptor:

```
$httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', '$injector', '$rootScope', function ($q, $injector, $rootScope) {
    return {
      'request': function (config) {
        if (config.url.indexOf('http') !== -1) {  
          config.showError = $rootScope.showError;
          $rootScope.showError = true;
          config.showLoading = $rootScope.showLoading;
          $rootScope.showLoading = true;  
          if (config.showLoading) {
            var $ionicLoading = $injector.get('$ionicLoading');
            $ionicLoading.show({
              template: '<ion-spinner icon="dots" class="spinner-energized"></ion-spinner>'
            });
          }
        }
        config.timeout = 40000;
        return config;
      },  
      'response': function (response) {
        $rootScope.retryHttp = 0;
        // do something on success
        if (response.config.showLoading) {
          var $ionicLoading = $injector.get('$ionicLoading');
          $ionicLoading.hide();
        }
```

When I inspect the code using a debugger, I notice that the `ionicLoading.show()` function is called both when the WebService has cached data and when it doesn't.

Comment: Are you sure it's not closing too quickly for you to notice ?
Place a breakpoint at `$ionicLoading.hide();` to see it closes too quickly.

Comment: @JuniorDev, I did it but nothing appears...